# TestFlight bug where AppleID is added as both internal and external

Tags: ios, testing, app-store-connect, testflight

Over the past couple of days I have seen one quite strange bug or problem with TestFlight.

- I invite a user as internal (technical role), he/she accepts the
  invitation.
- I go to Connect and select the user as test-flight internal user.
- Strangely the user is added as both internal and external test user, thus I am not being able to invite to test the app i want to.
- If I remove that user as external tester, the account gets deselected as internal tester. If I select the user as internal again, the whole bug with external reappears...

Anyone else with similar TestFLight problem or solution of how to solve that isssue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes i face this issue with almost all the apps. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I have an open ticket with Apple's support folks, still waiting on proper reply from them on that.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the support URL just for reference..

Comment: I was just able to get around this issue by deleting the user account from the list of iTunesConnect Users from the 'Users and Accounts' section and adding it again.
I am not yet sure if it means i just lost one internal tester spot.

Comment: It is internal ticket, via iTunes Connect, it is now being reviewed by senior supervisor in order to find if this is a bug with system (Of course it is!). Removing internal tester for me is not an option, it would require another round of setups for more than 10 people on my account.